# Python 3, Vim and Tmux - local installation

Tags: python-3.x, vi, tmux

How to locally install Python3, Vim, Tmux locally without root elevation on Ubuntu?

Comment: There's no actual question here. You should clarify your specific problem. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  See [How to ask good questions](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yep, sorry. I would like to remove the question. My mistake

Answer (score 0):

The installation of ncurses-6.0 and libevent-2.0.22-stable

The installation of Python3

```
$./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
$make && make install
```

The installation of Tmux 2.2:

```
$./configure CFLAGS="-I$HOME/local/include -I$HOME/local/include/ncurses" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/local/lib -L$HOME/local/include/ncurses -L$HOME/local/include" CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/local/include -I$HOME/local/include/ncurses" --prefix=$HOME/local
$make && make install
```

The installation of VIM 7.4:

```
$./configure CFLAGS="-I$HOME/local/include -I$HOME/local/include/ncurses" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/local/lib -L$HOME/local/include/ncurses -L$HOME/local/include" CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/local/include -I$HOME/local/include/ncurses" --prefix=$HOME/local --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --enable-rubyinterp --enable-python3interp --with-python-config-dir=$HOME/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m --enable-perlinterp --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope
$make && make install
```